# Sass couldn't be installed in NEAR project

Tags: reactjs, sass, nearprotocol

I have just created an app with `npx create-near-app --frontend="react" near-app-project`

Then I installed SASS with `yarn add sass` as stated in
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/

Now I get this error saying ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'***
[image]

As stated in the documentation, I have already renamed `global.css` to `global.scss`

I also tried uninstalling sass with `yarn remove sass` but the error still shows up.

What is causing this error? If NEAR app is built on top of ReactJS, the steps to installing sass should also be the same, isn't it?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Try to close and re-open the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can sometimes happen. Closing and re-opening the IDE may work.